# Google cloud messaging, unable to initialize receiver

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Im following the tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

I seem to have some issues registering my broadcastReceiver

I am getting the following error whenever the app runs, right after I register the device, and get the registration Id

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver
>   com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver

Here is the full stackTrace:

> > 06-19 01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-19 01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867):
> >     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver
> >     com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver:
> >     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver 06-19 01:08:03.994:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(23867):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2111)
> >     06-19 01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127) 06-19
> >     01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867):    at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
> >     06-19 01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867):  at
> >     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-19
> >     01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867):    at
> >     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-19 01:08:03.994:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(23867):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441) 06-19
> >     01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867):    at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-19
> >     01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867):    at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-19 01:08:03.994:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(23867):  at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
> >     06-19 01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867):  at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 06-19
> >     01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867):    at
> >     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-19 01:08:03.994:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(23867): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver 06-19 01:08:03.994:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(23867):  at
> >     dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
> >     06-19 01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867):  at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 06-19
> >     01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867):    at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 06-19
> >     01:08:03.994: E/AndroidRuntime(23867):    at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2106)

Here is the full manifest, with some of the activities cut off

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gotoohlala"
    android:versionCode="48"
    android:versionName="4.1.2" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <!--  Push notification -->
                <receiver
            android:name="pushNotification.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.gotoohlala" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

                <!--  Push notification END -->

        <activity
            android:name="launchOohlala.LaunchOohlala"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="launchOohlala.FakeLogin"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="launchOohlala.CheckEmail"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="discoverMyCampus.RulesFragment"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.gotoohlala" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/applicationId" />

         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDP2zfbRiEH0mNCkn2lpxm92DQHsfIJfPU" />

    </application>

       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <!-- Wifi related -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />


    <uses-permission android:name="com.gotoohlala.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <permission android:name="com.gotoohlala.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.gotoohlala.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 
    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
     <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.gotoohlala.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.gotoohlala.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

</manifest>
```

My GCMBroadcastReceiver class

```
package pushNotification;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.gotoohlala.OohlalaMain;

import discoverMyCampus.RulesFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Handling of GCM messages.
 */
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Context ctx;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("SUCCESS SUCCESS", "ONRECEIVE HAS BEEN CALLED, WOOT WOOT!!");
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        Log.d("SUCCESS SUCCESS", "ONRECEIVE HAS BEEN CALLED, WOOT WOOT!!");
        ctx = context;
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                    intent.getExtras().toString());
        } else {
            sendNotification("Received: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        }
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

    // Put the GCM message into a notification and post it.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
                new Intent(ctx, RulesFragment.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.getNotification());
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why Im not able to register the receiver?
Thanks

Comment: did you got the solution or not ??

Answer (score 5):

The app is looking for `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver`, but your class is in a different package `pushNotification.GCMBroadcastReceiver`.

And the package of your app is a different one - `com.myAppName`.

While your `GCMBroadcastReceiver` doesn't have to be in the same package as the package of your app, the category in the intent filter must be the package of the app.

You should change this :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="pushNotification" />
        </intent-filter>
```

To this :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.myAppName" />
        </intent-filter>
```

EDIT :

Based on your manifest, you have additional errors :

You specify the Broadcast Receiver twice. If you wish to use your own Receiver, you should remove this part :

```
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.gotoohlala" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Another problem :

Remove this line :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.gotoohlala.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Since you already have these lines (which are correct) :

```
<permission android:name="com.gotoohlala.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.gotoohlala.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, however im still getting the same error after doing the recommended changes. Another thing i should prob point out, is I have a test server on my phone, that pushes messages to the app, and im also getting the same error whenever I try to push the messages.

Comment: ok, i added the full manifests, minus some of the linked activities

Answer (score -1):

Try to check the v.4 library.
**Propreties->Java Build Path->Order and Export**